# Table to view with group_concat

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table and i want to generate a view. See the result.
How can i achieve that?
I tried with group_cat but that doesnt work :(

```
id product_id cat_id date
1  1          1      2018-05-01
2  1          1      2018-05-02
3  1          1      2018-05-04
4  1          1      2018-05-05
5  1          1      2018-05-06
6  1          1      2018-05-07
4  1          1      2018-05-08
5  1          1      2018-05-09
6  1          1      2018-05-10
7  1          2      2018-05-01
8  1          2      2018-05-02
9  1          2      2018-05-04
10  1          2      2018-05-05
11  1          2      2018-05-06
12  1          2      2018-05-07
13  1          2      2018-05-08
14  1          2      2018-05-09
15  1          2      2018-05-10
```

Result:

```
product_id cat_id dates
1          1      2018-05-01,2018-05-02,2018-05-03,2018-05-04,etc comma seperated
1          2      2018-05-01,2018-05-02,2018-05-03,2018-05-04,etc comma seperated
```

Query:

```
select
  tmp.product_id, tmp.cat_id, group_concat(tmp.date separator ',') as dates
from xxxx as tmp
group by tmp.cat_id;
```

Comment: Edit your question and show what you have tried. Also, explain what you mean by "doesn't work".

Comment: Column date's data type?

Comment: You hav error  .. using group_concat  ..? . (not group_cat) show us your code and eventually your error

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid see edit

Comment: Your group by should be `tmp.product_id, tmp.cat_id`

Comment: What does "Doesn't work" mean??

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid that did the trick :) Please give it as awnser!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your group by should be `tmp.product_id, tmp.cat_id`

```
select
  tmp.product_id, tmp.cat_id, group_concat(tmp.date separator ',') as dates
from demo as tmp
group by tmp.product_id, tmp.cat_id
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/854a57/1)

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer

Comment: is it also possible to do a group by on dates, i am getting an error.

Comment: @Bas can you show complete query in which you are trying a group by clause may be its better to ask a new one

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT product_id, cat_id, GROUP_CONCAT(date SEPARATOR ',') dates FROM `table_name` GROUP BY product_id, cat_id
```

Comment: Why are you wasting effort writing the same thing as in the first answer. Just cast an up vote on it.

Comment: Solution same, but almost same time. Did not notice that when I had started writing

Comment: I see I vote up!